# How To Get Text From Binded TextBlock Store App c#

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I want to get text from below TextBlock but i can't get it ??
Note : fname is property for setting text in TextBlock

```
 <TextBlock Name="getname" Text="{Binding Path=fname }"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried getname.Text ?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the text binding for a TextBlock is One-Way. You'll need to explicitly specify a Two-Way binding if you want to read the value back into your view model.

```
Text="{Binding Path=fname, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

If you're not using view models and you just want programmatic access to the text value you'll need to access the value in code-behind.

```
public string GetTextBlockText()
{
    return this.getname.Text;
}
```